# Significant Mann-Kendall but no Sen slope

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I am doing trend analysis with Mann-Kendall and Sen's slope in R. I am getting a significant trend (tau = 0.242, p < 0.05), but when I calculate the slope I get 0 ± 0. Why is this happening? I have performed these commands with other data and this never heppened...am I missing something?

Data are frequencies (number of an event per year). With barplots and other plot I clearly see an increasing trend, so the positive MannKendall value makes sense to me, but I don't understand 0 ± 0.
Can somebody please explain what's happening here? What am I doing wrong? Maybe Sen's method is not good for this kind of data?

```
MannKendall(data$freq) #library(Kendall)
sens.slope(data$freq, conf.level = 0.95) #library(trend)

data
   time freq
1  1982 0.00
2  1983 0.00
3  1984 0.00
4  1985 0.00
5  1986 0.38
6  1987 0.00
7  1988 2.23
8  1989 0.00
9  1990 0.00
10 1991 0.00
11 1992 0.00
12 1993 0.00
13 1994 0.62
14 1995 0.00
15 1996 0.00
16 1997 0.12
17 1998 0.00
18 1999 0.00
19 2000 0.00
20 2001 1.38
21 2002 0.00
22 2003 0.00
23 2004 0.00
24 2005 0.00
25 2006 0.00
26 2007 2.23
27 2008 0.00
28 2009 0.00
29 2010 0.00
30 2011 0.00
31 2012 1.00
32 2013 1.19
33 2014 3.00
34 2015 0.00
35 2016 1.23
36 2017 1.04
37 2018 0.00
38 2019 0.15
39 2020 2.19
40 2021 0.46
41 2022 0.00
```